# Select max id column with sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using sqlite in my Android project.
I can read/write successfully, but want to select maximum record of Avenue table.
My code:

```
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX([Id]) FROM [Avenue];", null);
  c.moveToFirst();
  String result = c.getString(0);
```

But return null value!

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `getString`? Shouldn't it be [`getInt`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29) or [`getLong`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getLong%28int%29)?

Comment: show your db structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int getLastID()
{
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT MAX("+COL_NAME+") FROM "+TABLE_NAME, null);
    int maxid = (cursor.moveToFirst() ? cursor.getInt(0) : 0);
    return maxid;
}
```

This should give you the last/max ID from ur table

Comment: What if, any record, at the last index, is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

To get the maximum value of the ID of a table, you can write your code like this:

```java
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "MY_TABLE";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";

@SuppressLint("Range")
public int getMaxId(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String selectQuery = String.format("SELECT MAX(%s) as MAX_ID FROM %s", KEY_ID, TABLE_NAME);

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    int id = -1;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("MAX_ID"));
    }
    return id;
}
```